# Cannot connect to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I have a problem with connecting to Facebook from my application. I had connected, logged-in and posted to Facebook via android emulator successfully but it failed when I exported it to my physical devices (both android smartphone and tablet). I don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: have you check your internet connection? while using in real device what shows in device either error or crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Update below code of your application.

```
public void loginAndPostToWall() {
    facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
            new LoginDialogListener());
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!I've connected to Facebook successfully already ^^

Comment: if this answer is helpful to you than accept it otherwise post answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Is the emulator using the same OS version as the physical phone? Does the phone have an actual internet connection (and does your app check for it)?

The android emulator will "magically" connect to the internet so long as your computer has internet. Your actual phone may not have a great internet signal, or may just be having a lot of latency.